# OS X not using most recent NumPY version

Tags: python, macos, numpy

Trying to update NumPY by running `pip install -U numpy`, which yields "Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages". Then checking the version with `import numpy` and `numpy.version.version` yields '1.6.2' (old version). Python is importing numpy via the path '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy'. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new NumPY version would install (via pip) into the System path, where it wasn't being recognized by Python. To solve this I ran `pip install --user numpy==1.7.1` to specify I want NumPY version 1.7.1 on my Python (user) path.
:)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the old version of numpy from

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy

.
Just delete the numpy package from there and then try to import numpy from the python shell.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm now having issues deleting numpy from here. Navigating to that /python directory and running `rm -r numpy` yields a bunch of override questions, and then numpy remains in the directory. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe sudo rm -r numpy

Comment: this gives me `rm: numpy: No such file or directory`...?